# Rails: Display similar products using a product's specific attribute in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Product model:

ID-- NAME-- product_code

1 --name1--- axdf

2-- name2--- ddfg

3 --name3 ---gghh

In my product 1 display page I want to show another section showing similar products available having same product_code. How do I display similar products having same product_code?

Do I create a method in my product controller such as:

```
def similar_products
 @similar_product.code= @product.product_code
end
```

or a scope in model

```
scope :similar_products, where :product_code= true
```

Comment: I would make a named_scope in Product that takes a product_code... but it's not clear if that would answer your question...

Comment: @Kirti, I tried these two methods above perhaps there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `scope` in your model `Product`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
   scope :similar_products, ->(product) { where("id != ? and product_code = ?", product.id, product.product_code) }  
  #...
end
```

This scope `similar_products` would fetch all the records from products table excluding the passed product object which have same product_code as that of the passed product object.

Access the `scoped` method in the `ProductsController#show` to get a list of similar products:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController 
    # ...
    def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      @similar_products = Product.similar_products(@product)
    end
    #...
end
```

Comment: With the above steps in the Model and the Controller, how do you display similar products in the products show page?